# Recommendations for a Fortran XML library

Tags: xml, fortran

Are there any recommendations for a Fortran XML library? I found a [few](http://www.google.com/search?q=fortran+xml), but I do not know how well they are supported.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  I looked at using Fortran + XML for another project but ended up using namelists instead since they were much easier to deal with.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The problem is that we want to transfer information to
 other parts of the system that are written in a modern language. Java etc. has nice XML APIs. Another approach I considered was calling C++ XML libs from Fortran

Comment: Tim PS: I wonder if we have met before. I work at NCAR partially on the ESMF project.

Comment: I have a university lecturer who uses Fortan lots and XML even more. I'll see what I can find out, although it might take a week or so.

Comment: You might try taking a shot of posting this on comp.lang.fortran. I know someone there is using XML, but I can't remember who, nor do I have the links (never had the need for that, so ...). Anyways, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Toby White has written a very useful library FoX to be found at:

http://uszla.me.uk/space/software/FoX/

It provides a library which is able to read and write XML in Fortran95. It is widely used in the computational chemistry and mineralogy community - I don't know how far outside.
I use FoX whenever I have Fortran program that needs to emit XML.

Toby has now moved on, but I expect that you will be able to run FoX without problems unless your machine has an unusal compiler. I expect that if you have questions Toby will be able to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

[F77xml](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/munehiro/f77xml/), although it needs gdome2